# Powershell AD lookup by name and samaccountname variables

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Two questions, first one is probably quite simple but it's extremely annoying. I'm running a script for AD lookup with the user name variable as an attribute:

```
[string]$FirstName = Read-Host "User First Name"
[string]$LastName = Read-Host "User Last Name"
[string]$FullName = "*$FirstName* *$LastName*"
write-host
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $FullName} -properties * | select-object name, samaccountname | sort-object
read-host "Press Enter to exit"
```

The problem is that "read host" is interpret as a part of the same command, and the query results appear after the prompt. I'd like to pause the script so the results can be read from the screen before console closes by hitting Enter. I've been experimenting with the brackets or different kind of loops but haven't been able to figure out how this should be done.

My second question is that I want to have samaccountname as a search attribute. Something like this:

```
[string]$Login = Read-Host "User Login name"
[string]$LoginName = "*$Login*"
```

The variable should be added to filter similar way the FullName variable is used.

Comment: Please break this down into two questions.  Not fair to the answerers otherwise.  Down-voting because of it.

Answer (score 0):

1.)
A better way to pause the script and only continue after input, is to use:

```
$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") > $null
```

The Query should come after the display of the Get-ADUser, if it still isn't working maybe submit some output examples or try getting the AD-User from `Get-ADUser *  | Where-Object {$_.Fullname like $Fullname}`

2.)I'm not fully understanding your problem here, but if you want to get and User by his login name you can do it like this:

```
$login = Read-Host "Login name"
Get-ADUser $login | select-object name, samaccountname | sort-object
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this does the same thing. Script pauses, and after key is pressed the query result is shown. As a side note: I did some Googling and the ReadKey method is not supported by ISE. 

About my second question: I meant that I'd like to have the query results based on name and/or samaccountname. So that the query would have three search criteria: first name, second name or the login name. The problem is how to include these three variables with dynamic content to same query pipeline.

Comment: Regarding three parameters in your get-ADUser, the -Filter argument can be chained with -or or -and depending on how you want to filter. Try, for instance: Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $FullName -or SamAccountname -like $Login}

Comment: As for the problem with the prompt coming before the command output... I'm really not sure. you could try a [Console]::Out.Flush()  after your Get-ADUser, perhaps. Or remove the Write-Host preceding the Get-ADUser... it really isn't that necessary, I think

Comment: I have already tried Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $FullName -and samaccountname -like $Login} -properties *, but search filter is not recognized. The second parameter cannot be chained to same filter. I guess it needs to be divided somehow.

Comment: Well i cant even find the User by the indicator Fullname in the way you do it, why even bother to filter for full name? The login exists only once so why filter by another faktor?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this myself. For the first question, adding "format-table" to the end of the pipeline closed the command and the script proceeded normally after that.

For the second question, as a workaround I just broke down the query as two separate ones. First one is searching for the full name, and the second one is searching for the login name:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $FullName} -properties * | select-object name, samaccountname | sort-object name | format-table
write-host
Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like $LoginName} -properties * | select-object name, samaccountname | sort-object name | format-table
```

Answer (score 0):

Good for you finding a solution to your problem,

I will put here also what I did and maybe you can use it.

First of all the first part:

```
$FirstName = Read-Host "Please provide the Fist name of the User: "
$LastName = Read-Host "Please provide the Last name of the User: "
$Fullname = "$FirstName $LastName"
$Users= Get-AdUser -Filter {name -like $FullName} -Properties * | Select Name, Samaccountname | Sort-Object -Verbose
Get-AdUser -Filter {name -like $FullName} -Properties * | Select Name, Samaccountname | Sort-Object -Verbose
#$Users
```

you can uncomment the last user variable to get the results on your screen.

as of your second question you can use the -or so you can search with the $fullname or the $login

```
$Login = Read-Host "User Login name"
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $FullName -or samaccountname -like $Login } -properties *
```

I would prefer a selection before running the code as I do with my checks on the AD

if you want to send you the code I can do it, I just don't want to put in this answer something different from what you ask.